# Get HTTP server-push data stream

Tags: php, http, multipart, server-push, http-streaming

An external application provides me data with HTTP
server-push. I call the API function and then I'm constantly receiving event notifications.  API send me XML data stream like below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=boundary

--boundary
Content-Type: application/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Length: 486
<EventNotificationAlert version="2.0" xmlns="Oops:The page you are visiting may have been deleted,renamed or inaccessible.">
<dateTime>2017-03-17T11:43:04+01:00</dateTime>
<eventDescription>alarm</eventDescription>
</EventNotificationAlert>

--boundary
Content-Type: application/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Length: 480
<EventNotificationAlert version="2.0" xmlns="Oops:The page you are visiting may have been deleted,renamed or inaccessible.">
<dateTime>2017-03-17T11:47:47+01:00</dateTime>
<eventDescription>alarm</eventDescription>
</EventNotificationAlert>
```

I need to get each DateTime and EventDescription of the XML content data stream and insert it in the database. How to manage a stream of data? Which technology would be the best?

PHP was in my mind, but I don't know how to approach this issue, I am just lost.

Comment: How do you call that api?

Comment: I am using curl from my linux command line to check API response `curl -s -N -u user:pass  http://theapi.com/EventNotificationAlert/Stream` but I do nothing with PHP... any clue where start?

Comment: I'm trying to undestand this api; does `curl` end or it keeps the connection open?

Comment: `curl` close the connection after a while without data stream...

Comment: then you should not use `curl` and `php` together, IMHO, as you can not get the data

Comment: API documentation says: "/EventNotificationAlert/Stream description: It is used to get the event notification data stream through HTTP. Client system can call this API to initialize a stream of event info from the system. A connection is establish when this function is called, and stays open to constantly receive event notifications. "

Comment: So any advice to get data stream with PHP?

Comment: No necessarily with `PHP` but `PHP` with `curl` seem not applicable here. Do you need/require to use `PHP`?

Comment: `PHP` is part of my stack, so I prefer use `PHP`if there is a solution.

Comment: `PHP` is my preferred language, however, `PHP` is not good as long running process.

Comment: After some searching I found a partial solution: If the server closes the connection then you get the body, you could use https://github.com/dickolsson/http-multipart to parse the multiparts

Comment: If the server does not close the connection and it sends data as it is available on its side, then `PHP` does not fit and you should look into `nodejs`